# How to POST HTTPS request using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, https

I want to know how to make a HTTPS request from a VBScript client.

After receiving the request, how to decrypt the HTTPS response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTPS is not just an encryption format - it's a transport security protocol, with complex negotiation built-in. Just like you wouldn't try to build an HTTP client component in VBScript, similarly you wouldn't try to build an HTTPS/SSL client.

The VBScript language doesn't include any HTTP or HTTPS client, but windows has a couple of COM objects that can be used (from Windows Script Host of from ASP pages written in VBScript), and VBScript code running in internet explorer can similarly access a browser object that allows HTTPS calls.

From windows (WSH/ASP), the best object is typically MSXML2.ServerXmlHTTP, for example see this quick overview: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3272/posting-form-data-to-a-web-page/2/

From Internet Explorer, as long as you're not dealing with legacy versions, the best idea is to use the cross-browser standard object XMLHttpRequest. The following page gives you an overview: http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

All of these HTTP clients also support HTTPS.

Comment: I tried the  code of the link http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3272/posting-form-data-to-a-web-page/2/ you provided  and it doesn't work with `https`! (Only with `http`). Have you tested/checked the link yourself? If not, it's not OK!
Anyway, none of the links you provided contain `https`. This is not OK either.

Comment: @Apostolos I won't spend much time on your strangely aggressive comments... The MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object does normally support HTTPS, and will have worked for hundreds or thousands of visitors to this question - but it does rely on a lot of windows operating system machinery which can fail in different ways. I don't know the -2147012744 error code you mention below, but my guess is **either** that there's something broken in your Windows deployment, **or** that it is not compatible with the HTTPS server you're trying to reach, eg Windows XP is not supported by many servers these days.

Comment: You already spent too much! :) I am sorry for the offence. I just hate to see code that doesn't work (it produces errors). I have posted a lot of code in here and I always test it before doing so. And I expect other programmers to do the same thing. That's all.

Answer (score 7):

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xHttp.Open "GET", "https://yourhost.example.com/foo", False

' 2 stands for SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS
' 13056 means ignore all server side cert error
xHttp.setOption 2, 13056
xHttp.Send

' read response body
WScript.Echo xHttp.responseBody
```

Reference:

- [getOption Method of XML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [setOption Method of XML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `xHttp.responseBody` should be `xHttp.responseText`. Used it for setting up Facebook API requests which demands HTTPS. Though I suppose it is very bad practice by safety means, just bypassing all errors, it works for testing.

Comment: Your code doesn't work with `https`. (Only with `http`). `xHttp.Send` produces runtime error -2147012744. Have you tested your code?