# send data to PHP using .vbs

Tags: vbscript

i need a .vbs script to read the contents of a file, and send it with POST or GET to an online hosted php
been browsing the entire website, didnt find any solution
can anyone help ?
curl.exe is not usefull in my case

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907089/how-to-post-https-request-using-vbscript/5907741#5907741) has a link that explains running a post request in VBScript

Answer (score 1):

Write a script in VBS and execute using cscript.  Here's a page with lots of examples: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/xmlhttp.htm